# MembershipProvider and web.config

Tags: web-config, membership-provider

Where can I get a list of all the configuration properties for the Membership provider that can be added to the web.config, i.e.

```
<membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MembershipProvider" type="Providers.MembershipProvider, Providers" description="membership provider" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx

Comment: Also found that using Red Gate's .NET Reflector was very useful too

Comment: Reflector is a must have for every .net developer :-)

Comment: Target site is no longer available

Comment: They obviously f'd it up at MSDN, here's a snapshot I found:
http://web.archive.org/web/20101114191103/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx